# Zimbalaka: What is the full path to directory in celeryd.conf?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, paths

I am trying to install and run Zimbalaka (a Zim file creator for Offline MediaWiki in an app like [Kiwix](https://www.kiwix.org)) in an Ubuntu Desktop 18.10.
At a certain point, [instructions](https://github.com/tecoholic/Zimbalaka) tell to modify a line to contain the full path to the zimbalaka directory.

However, the path I have to type is not clear to me, so here are my questions:

- I cloned Zimbalaka to ~/Downloads with the command `git clone https://github.com/tecoholic/Zimbalaka.git`. Is the path `/home/[user]/Downloads/Zimbalaka/zimbalaka`?
- If this is NOT the case, could someone tell me what path I have to specify?

Find here below the instructions I made myself based on the instructions found [here](https://github.com/tecoholic/Zimbalaka) (some comments are added by me). It is the last line that lead to my question:

- Install libzim (already installed in my case)
- Install zimwriterfs (already installed in my case)

  ```
  sudo apt-get install libzim-dev libxml2-dev libxslt-dev python-dev zlib1g-dev python-pip python-virtualenv libapache2-mod-wsgi
  sudo apt install tcl #is needed for Redis installation
  sudo apt install git #needed for following command
  git clone https://github.com/tecoholic/Zimbalaka.git
  cd ~/Downloads/Zimbalaka
  virtualenv env
  . env/bin/activate
  pip install -r requirements.txt
  cd ..
  wget http://download.redis.io/releases/redis-3.0.1.tar.gz
  tar xzf redis-3.0.1.tar.gz
  cd redis-3.0.1
  sudo make && make install
  sudo ./utils/install_server.sh # maintain defaults except datastore location
  At prompt "Please select the redis port for this instance: [6379]", press Enter/Return
  Screen reads: Selecting default: 6379
  At prompt "Please select the redis config file name [/etc/redis/6379.conf]", press Enter/Return
  Screen reads: Selected default - /etc/redis/6379.conf
  At prompt "Please select the redis log file name [/var/log/redis_6379.log]", press Enter/Return
  Screen reads: Selected default - /var/log/redis_6379.log
  At prompt "Please select the data directory for this instance [/var/lib/redis/6379]", press Enter/Return
  Screen reads: Selected default - /var/lib/redis/6379
  At prompt "Please select the redis executable path [/usr/local/bin/redis-server]", press Enter/Return
  Screen reads the following:
      Selected config:
      Port           : 6379
      Config file    : /etc/redis/6379.conf
      Log file       : /var/log/redis_6379.log
      Data dir       : /var/lib/redis/6379
      Executable     : /usr/local/bin/redis-server
      Cli Executable : /usr/local/bin/redis-cli
      Is this ok? Then press ENTER to go on or Ctrl-C to abort.
  Press Enter/Return
  Screen reads the following:
      Copied /tmp/6379.conf => /etc/init.d/redis_6379
      Installing service...
      Success!
      Starting Redis server...
      Installation successful!
  (Put zimwriterfs somewhere or compile and install) ← Already installed
  (Edit zimbalaka/default_settings.py to reflect your production environment) ← Not edited
  nano celeryd.conf #instructions mention to edit celery.conf but it does not exist
  Modify line: directory=/full/path/to/zimbalaka to directory=/home/[user]/Downloads/Zimbalaka/zimbalaka
  ```

Comment: It should be `/home/[user]/Downloads/Zimbalaka/`!

Comment: Thank you @GeorgeUdosen, I corrected as per your comment. Alas Zimbalaka still does not work, but I have other questions that I am asking elsewhere (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1106396/zimbalaka-what-is-the-full-path-to-directory-in-zimbalaka-wsgi).

Comment: If the comment changed your question, please [edit] and change it! Else please add the answer below.

Comment: @dessert the comment did not change my question. It hopefully answered it, but as I have more questions, I asked them in different posts (see the link in my previous comment).